# ошибка при импорте метода OpenGL

Tags: c#, opengl

при импорте метода `glCopyBufferSubData` выдаёт ошибку

> EntryPointNotFoundException

при этом метод `gl.GetString(GL_VERSION)` возвращает 4.6.0
в чём проблема?

Comment: Может видео-драйвер староват...попробуйте накатить более свежий. Либо он слишком новый - тоже как вариант